# easeljs Stage width and height are half their specified value

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

I'm new to EaselJS and I've been having trouble positioning shapes correctly on the stage for days now. It's only today that I discovered that, while I set the canvas width and height to 800px and 450px respectively, easeljs seems to assume that the width is 400px and the height 225px (half of the set values).

I'm pretty sure I must be doing something wrong so could someone please look at this code and see what's causing the issue:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ludacris Labs</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8'></meta>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/index.css'/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/TestTube.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/index.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id='canvas' width='800' height='450'>
            This application will not run on your browser because your browser is out of date.
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.css**

```
#canvas{
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

**index.js**

```
function init()
{
    var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
    var dimensions = {
        width: $('#canvas').width(),//800
        height: $('#canvas').height()//450
    };

    var solution = new TestTube('water','blue');
    stage.addChild(solution);
    solution.x = dimensions.width/2-100;//300
    solution.y = 0.44*dimensions.height/2;//99
    solution.width = 50;
    solution.height = 0.55*dimensions.height;//247.5
    solution.level = 90;
    solution.render();

    stage.update();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    init();
});
```

**TestTube.render**

```
    TestTube.prototype.render = function(){

        console.log(this.name,this.x,this.y,this.level);

        this.graphics.clear();

        this.graphics.setStrokeStyle(2,1,1);
        //set stroke color black.
        this.graphics.beginStroke("#000000");
        //set fill color 
        this.graphics.beginFill(this.color);
       //START DRAWING------------------------------------

    //move to origin.
    this.graphics.moveTo(this.x,this.y);

    //draw line uptil point of liquid in test tube [liquid start point]
    _level = (100 - this.level)/100;
    this.graphics.lineTo(this.x,this.y+_level*this.height);

    //draw line uptil bottom of test tube.
    this.graphics.lineTo(this.x,this.y+(this.height-this.width/2));

    //draw the round part of test tube.
    //graphics.arc(centerX,centerY,radius,startAngle,endAngle,anticlockwise);
    this.graphics.arc(this.x + this.width/2,this.y+(this.height-this.width/2),this.width/2,Math.PI,0,true);

    //go back to upto level of liquid in tube [liquid end point]
    this.graphics.lineTo(this.x+this.width,this.y+_level*this.height);

    //connect liquid start point with liquid end point to fill in liquid colour.
    this.graphics.lineTo(this.x,this.y+_level*this.height);
    this.graphics.endFill();

    //go back to liquid end point
    this.graphics.moveTo(this.x+this.width,this.y+_level*this.height);

    //draw the rest of the test tube.
    this.graphics.lineTo(this.x+this.width,this.y);

    //stop drawing.
    this.graphics.endStroke();

}
```

**Screenshot**
Based on the code on index.js, you'd expect the test tube to appear near the centre of the canvas, but it appears on the bottom-right because the canvas size used is half of the canvas size set. 
[image]

Comment: Can you also post the code where the tube-contents are actually drawn?  From looking at the rest of your code it looks okay, so my current guess is that you don't draw the contents 0-centered, but x/y-centered. If you can, put it online somewhere or on jsfiddle.

Comment: I've posted the rest of the drawing code. What is this 0-centred drawing thing you speak of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is with the drawing-coordinates inside your shape:
Each object (Bitmap, Shape, MovieClip, ect.) in EaselJS has its' own coordinate-space.
That means: If you place the shape at: `100|100`  AND  draw a dot at `this.x|this.y (100|100)` your dot will appear on the stage at `200|200`.
What you should do instead is to use `0|0` as your base and not `this.x|this.y`.

```
//move to origin.
this.graphics.moveTo(0,0);

//draw line uptil point of liquid in test tube [liquid start point]
_level = (100 - this.level)/100;
this.graphics.lineTo(0,0+_level*this.height);

//...and so on...
```

---

**Trivia**

The benefits of that are: If you remove the Shape and add it to a different container, it will be automatically positioned relative to that new containers' position.
Also: You do not have to worry about the absolut position of an object, this comes in very handy with more complex constructs with multiple shapes and containers. You only need to know the position relative to the parent-container.

Comment: Wait, so you're saying I should replace every instance of `this.x` and `this.y` in the render method with 0?

Comment: yes, because the drawing-methods already have this.x and this.y as their base, putting in this.x and this.y once again will "double" the positions, which lead to your impression of just having a 50% stage size

Comment: I made that change in the render method and consequently, the test tube was drawn at the origin and not in the coordinates I gave.

Comment: Now you can adjust the position via `solution.x` and `y` and just call `stage.update()` - if that is not what you are looking for, then I probably got your question wrong. Probably best if you made a jsfiddle with your issue :)